# Why can't I set Values in my state using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm trying to set data in my state over a function... the state is called as values and this is the code that I have

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
     about:'',ourServiceBuyer:'',ourServiceSupplier:'',faq:[],products:[]
 });

 useEffect(() => {

   async function handleData() {
     try {
       const result = await LandingData()

       console.log('algo',result.data.landing.about_us )

       setValues({  
         about:result.data.landing.about_us,
         ourServiceBuyer:result.data.landing.our_services_supplier,
         ourServiceSupplier :result.data.landing.our_services_supplier,
         faq : result.data.landing_page_faq,
         products:result.data.products, 
       });

       console.log("resultado de useEffect mostrando los values",values)
       console.log("resultado de useEffect", result);

     } catch (e) {

       console.error('error in obatin the return of LandingData: ', e.message);

       handleRedirect('/WrongRequest');
     }
   }
   handleData()

 }, []);
```

`landingData()` provides me with the data that I need, and I can see it with a `console.log()` But, when I try to set the data to the state I don't get anything only the same initial state...

Comment: setting the state is react is async so the state won't be changed when reach you "console.log" for it

Comment: I don't see anything overtly incorrect with this code. Can you provide a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: try putting console outside useEffect, you will see update value there

Answer (score 0):

i put "await" before this sentence

console.log("resultado de useEffect mostrando los values",values)